# Delete file from folder and subfolder

Tags: php

I have a php script that uploads a photo to a main folder and copies it into a subfolder. I also have a php script that deletes the photo. The problem is that it only deletes the photo from the main folder and not the subfolder. This is the code I tried to come up with but nothing happens. Any thoughts?

```
$deletefile = $galleriesfolder.$folder.$dir.$image; 
    $deletefile1 = $galleriesfolder.$folder.$dir."/thumbs/".$image; 
    unlink($deletefile); 
    if (!is_file($deletefile)):
        die("no file");
    endif;
    unlink($deletefile1); 
    if (!is_file($deletefile1)):
        die("no file");

    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Deletes all subfolders and files in a directory recursively

```
/**
 * Deletes a directory and all files and folders under it
 * @return Null
 * @param $dir String Directory Path
 */
function rmdir_files($dir) {
 $dh = opendir($dir);
 if ($dh) {
  while($file = readdir($dh)) {
   if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) {
    if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
     unlink($dir.$file);
    }
    else if (is_dir($dir.$file)) {
     rmdir_files($dir.$file);
    }
   }
  }
  rmdir($dir);
 }
}
```

This is quite a nasty function.
You want to handle it with care. Make sure you don't delete any directories that you do not intend to delete. It will attempt to remove the whole directory, and all files in it.
It does no error checking apart from making sure a directory handle was opened successfully for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This code will deletes all subfolders and files in a directory recursively.

```html
$dir = "/";
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$ri = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, `enter code here`RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($ri as $file)
{
         $file->isDir() ? rmdir($file) : unlink($file);
}
```